# Find BPM percentage difference using math - something not adding up right?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I asked this question about 2 and a half years ago on how to find the percentage difference between 2 bpms ( I apologize if this seems extremely simple... my math / algebra skills are not that good, I fell asleep in all of my algebra classes in highschool and was put in the dumb math class):
[How to find percentage change between original and final BPM](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1796339/how-to-find-percentage-change-between-original-and-final-bpm)

At the time all my original files were 100bpm... but now I want to be able to have different source bpms... so I changed the source bpm to 120 and desired bpm to 85 and I get -.35 but when I subtract 35% from 120bpm I get 42 not 85... what am I doing wrong?

```
If your initial number is a and your final number is b, then the percentage change x from a to b is given by
x=b−a100
For example, if a=100 and b=134, then
x=134−100100=0.34=34%
If a=100 and b=78, then
x=78−100100=−0.22=−22%
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do $$\frac{120-85}{120}\approx0.29$$
If you want in percent, multiply the answer by $100$.
Also the number $42$ is $35\%$ of $120$, not $65\%$.

Comment: Thanks Andrei... I think I was dividing by 100 not 120 and that is where I got confused... because I was thinking I was dividing by 100% but it should be the original number now I see.. Thank you!